# glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) - not rendering anything

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, depth-buffer, bit-depth

im working on a project to learn to render 3d shapes. to get the depth right i am trying to use glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST). as expected it will not render anything with ony that addition so i added glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT), but still i do not get a single thing rendered. here is a simplified version of my code.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    initDisplay();
    gameLoop();
    cleanUp();
}
public static void initDisplay(){
    try {

        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(500,500));
        Display.create();

    } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


public static void gameLoop(){
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = -20;
    float cubeX = 0;
    float cubeY = 0;
    float cubeZ = 0;
    float apothem = 1;
    float aspect = Display.getWidth()/Display.getHeight();
    Camera cam = new Camera(aspect,70,0.0f, 1000);
    Cube cube = new Cube(1);
    while(!Display.isCloseRequested() && Display.isActive()){
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)){
            x+=.003;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
            x-=.003;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)){
            z-=.003;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)){
            z+=.003;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)){
            cubeZ+=.03;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)){
            cubeZ-=.03;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)){
            cubeX+=.03;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)){
            cubeX-=.03;
        }
        cam.setX(x);
        cam.setY(y);
        cam.setZ(z);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glLoadIdentity();
        cam.useView();
        cube.render(cubeX,cubeY,cubeZ);
        Display.update();
    }
```

}

this is the class used to create and render a cube

```
public class Cube {
float apothem;
Cube(float apothem){
    this.apothem = apothem;
}
public void render(float x, float y, float z){

    glPushMatrix();

        glRotatef(x,1,0,0);
        glRotatef(y,0,1,0);
        glRotatef(z,0,0,1);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            //front face
            glColor3f(.22f, .64f, .14f);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,-apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,-apothem,apothem);

            //back face
            glColor3f(.23f, .26f, .64f);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,-apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,-apothem,-apothem);

            //left face
            glColor3f(.72f, .16f, .39f);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,-apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,-apothem,-apothem);

            //right face
            glColor3f(.53f, .21f, .84f);
            glVertex3d(apothem,-apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,-apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,apothem,apothem);

            //top face
            glColor3f(.42f, .99f, .37f);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,apothem,apothem);

            //bottom face
            glColor4f(.44f, .11f, .74f,25f);
            glVertex3d(apothem,-apothem,-apothem);
            glVertex3d(apothem,-apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,-apothem,apothem);
            glVertex3d(-apothem,-apothem,-apothem);
       glEnd();
   glPopMatrix();




}
```

}
this is the camera im using to view things

```
private float x,y,z;
private float rx,ry,rz;

private float aspect;
private float fov;
private float zNear, zFar;

Camera(float aspect, float fov, float zNear, float zFar){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    rx = 0;
    ry = 0;
    rz = 0;
    this.aspect = aspect;
    this.fov = fov;
    this.zNear = zNear;
    this.zFar = zFar;
    initProjection();

}
private void initProjection(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
public void useView(){
    glRotatef(rx,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(ry,0,1,0);
    glRotatef(rz,0,0,1);
    glTranslatef(x,y,z);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the depth function? After you enable depth test, use this: `glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);`.

Comment: Also, to clarify, it does render the cube *when you don't have depth test enabled*?

Comment: In addition to setting the `glDepthFunc()`, have you set the depth you want to clear the buffer to? (Just like you set `glClearColor()`, you also need to set [`glClearDepth()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearDepth.xml).)

Comment: In addition to everything else, have you requested a depth buffer from your WM?

Comment: @aib From my experience, I don't think you need to do that in LWJGL.

Comment: First, don't set your near clipping plane to zero; 1.0 is a better choice.  Second, it's likely you're object isn't in the viewing frustum.  Try simplifying `useView` to merely be a simple translation `glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, -0.5*(zNear + zFar));  That viewing transform will put the origin in the middle of your viewing frustum, and since you render the cube around the origin, that should at least make it visible

Comment: i create a camera first which calls to enable depth test, glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); makes it show but makes depth test useless, the parts that should be closer still render behind the others

Comment: and yes it does render without depth test

Comment: @ShaneAbramMendez So, let me clarify this one last time. It will render the cube fine without depth test enabled, and when depth test *is* enabled, the cube will render but the faces will not be rendered in the right order?

Comment: you understand how it looks before depth test is enabled right?
without depthtest it renders like youd expect. but once depthtest is added it wont render anything. even with the addition of glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)